# Renewing the queue manager's certificate

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

One of our queue managers certificate is about to expire, it is been advised that renewing it is much cheaper than replacing the old one. These are the below steps which we are following(Through IBM Key Management):

1. Choose the personal certificate and select re-create - Renewal.csr
2. Send the Renewal.csr to CA for COMODO certificate - RenewedComodo
3. Choose the personal certificate and select Receive to import RenewedComodo. ( Refresh Security )

When creating a new certificate we opt for Personal Certificate Request and select new.This is the first step. and we follow the 2 and 3 steps.

Here is my query, other than selecting the re-create, there is no difference I had set up.

1. When I have two certificates as RenewalCOMODO and oldCOMODO, how do queue manager knows which is righteous.?
2. If it selects which is not expired, won't it be having the expired one in the database?
3. If we need to delete the old one, after adding the renewed one, How will it be different from replacing the certificates?

Answer (score 1):

This will require a little background before getting to the answers.

When you initially created the CSR what you actually got was a public/private key pair and a Certificate Signing Request or "CSR".  The CSR contains the public key and the requested attributes such as Distinguished Name.  The CSR is signed with your private key so that any recipient can use the embedded public key to validate that the CSR and the requested attributes have not been tampered with.

What is less well known is that the CA is not bound to apply all the attributes that were provided in the CSR.  For example, if the certificate purchased is a Domain Validated certificate and the CSR contains values for the OU field, the CA will simply delete them leaving only the DN and SAN fields plus their own information.  Thus the certificate you get back may have different fields than the original CSR.

When you recreate the CSR from an in-use certificate the same process occurs again except that new CSR reflects any changes that the CA made originally.  Close inspection of the original CSR and the newly generated one commonly show differences in the SAN or that an email contact has been added to the DN.  However, from the CA's point of view these differences are cosmetic.

With that in mind, let's look at the questions again.

> When I have two certificates as RenewalCOMODO and oldCOMODO, how do queue manager know which is right?

Assuming that you are talking about the artifacts the CA has provided after responding to the original and renewal CSR, the QMgr does not know which is which.  You can run the `receive` command on either and, assuming both of them were signed by the same CA and use the same signer chain, either will work.

*It is the administrator's responsibility to verify that the correct certificate is installed.*

> If it selects which is not expired, won't it be having the expired one in the database?

No.  Each successful `receive` command keeps the private portions of the personal certificate and replaces the public portions.  The label is associated with the private portion and this is checked for uniqueness so you cannot (or at least *should* not if there are no bugs) be able to have two copies in the same KDB.

> If we need to delete the old one, after adding the renewed one, How will it be different from replacing the certificates?

Just make sure you receive the correct certificate.  Always do a `runmqakm -cert -details` command or inspect the cert using the GUI.

Additional recommendations:

- Always make a copy of the KDB before working on it.
- Keep copies of your CSRs and certs in the KDB directory.
- I like to use timestamps in the file names so it is obvious what the history was.  My file names all start with YYYYMMDD like `20150908_QMName_CSR.arm` and `20150908_QMName_CSR_signed.arm`.
- Make sure that the file permissions of the certificate files, KDB, and directory holding them are set to deny any access by anyone other than the MQM service account.  If that's not possible, allow group access but make sure the members of the mqm group are as few as possible.  *Anyone who can read the certificates can use them.  It is not necessary to know the password to the KDB to use the certs it contains*.
- When performing maintenance, I like to make a new copy of the KDB (with timestamped file name as described earlier) and when I'm sure it is ready I change the QMgr's `SSLKEYR` attribute to point to it.  I then change the old file to be read-only and issue `RESET SECURITY TYPE(SSL)` on the QMgr.
- Always remember to issue `RESET SECURITY TYPE(SSL)` on the QMgr.  It is a rather disruptive command so try to not issue it when the QMgr is busy.  It will require all channels to shut down and lots of reconnect attempts will prevent it from completing quickly.